# Adaptation of sum of arrival times of Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $\{N_t\}_{t\geq0}$ be a Poisson process and $\{F_t\}_{t\geq0}$ be its nautral filtration so that $\{N_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is adapted. $T_i$ be the $i$th arrival time of Poisson process of arrival rate $\lambda$, given $t>0$, prove if $\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} T_i$ is also adapted to $\{F_t\}_{t\geq0}$?

Comment: A process is adapted relative to a specific filtration. Are you asking if it is adapted to $\{F_t\}_{t\geq0}$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: I would say yes, because $T(N)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} T_i$ is $F_t$-measurable, i.e., $P(T(N)=t|\{F_s\}_{s\leq t})$ So you can assign a probability measure to the sum, T(N), given a filtration on the number of counts up to time t using the measure on that filtration. E.g., T(5)=6, is is the poisson probability of 5 counts in 6 time units. This is measurabe using any previous filtration, and the probability will change as you aquire more information on the counts.

Comment: It's your first claim that I need a rigorous proof. I mean, by definition, $F_t=\sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t)$, where $N_s=max\{n\geq0; T_n\leq s\}$, then how to show explicitly that $\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} T_i$ is $F_t$-measurable, i.e., $\sigma(\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} T_i)\subset \sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t)$?

Comment: See hint below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L_t=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_t}T_i$, then $L_t=\int\limits_0^t(N_t-N_s)\mathrm ds$. Since $(N_s)_{0\leqslant s\leqslant t}$ is $F_t$-measurable, this proves that $L_t$ is $F_t$-measurable.

To prove the key-formula used above, *fubinize* $L_t$, that is, using the identity $[s\lt T_i]=[N_s\lt i]$, write $L_t$ as
$$
L_t=\sum\limits_{i\geqslant1}\mathbf 1_{i\leqslant N_t}\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{s\lt T_i}\mathrm ds=\int_0^\infty \sum\limits_{i\geqslant1}\mathbf 1_{N_s\lt i\leqslant N_t}\mathrm ds=\int_0^\infty(N_t-N_s)^+\mathrm ds.
$$

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. $T_i$ are arrival times not inter-arrival times so $L_t$ is not the date of the last event before $t$ but the sum of all the previous arrival times.

Comment: @user2690457: Normally you think of the poisson process in terms of interarrival times and counts. The actual time value is arbitrary. I'm not even sure what such a sum represents if its a sum of "absolute" times.

Comment: In my notation, $T_1, T_2-T_1,...,T_n-T_{n-1},...$ are independent exponential random variable with coefficient $\lambda
$, so $\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}T_i$ could be understood as $\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}(\sum_{k=1}^i(T_k-T_{k-1}))$, this is not something weird that I make up from my mind, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral $\int_0^tsdM_s$ is just $\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}T_i-\lambda t^2/2$, where $M_s=N_s-\lambda s$ is the compensated Poisson process

Comment: Whom is this last comment addressed to?

Comment: In last comment I just tried to explain my motivation to Eupraxis1981, I'm still studying your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partition of sigma field on $N_s$ according to the value of $N_s$: $\sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t) =\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} [(\bigcup_{k=1}^{t}\{N_k=i\})\cap \sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t)]$. Your event, $N_T :=\{\sum_{i=1}^{N} T_i = T\}$ can be mapped to the set $[\{N_T=N\}\cap \sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t)] \subset [(\bigcup_{k=1}^{t}\{N_k=N\})\cap \sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t)]\subset \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} [(\bigcup_{k=1}^{t}\{N_k=i\})\cap \sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t)] = \sigma(N_s; 0\leq s\leq t)$

Comment: What do you mean by $\bigcup_{k=1}^t\{N_k=i\}$? Here t is a positive real number and do you mean k is also real number? Hence the union is uncountable?

Comment: See Did's response above as well for an elegant derivation. As for mine, the index t in $N_t$ ranges over the positive reals, so your sigma field is uncountable. What the uncountable union is doing is forming a "filter" for the subsequent intersection, since it will pick out all members of $F_t$ that share a certain count value, across all times $[0,\infty)$ The first union just puts them all back together to get the original set of all values of N for each value of t.